# How to emulate a mouse scroll for the current window opened?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I'm currently trying to emulate a mouse scroll event on the current window opened.I'm implementing it using setscrollpos() function in visual C++.

```
    SetScrollPos(hwnd,SB_VERT,0,TRUE);

    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
```

How does one pass the name of current window opened to the parameter hwnd?

Comment: Are you trying to send this message to a different application? If so, your question would be better thought of as "How to get hwnd of a specific window?" You may use SendInput when you have that hwnd to _correctly_ simulate user input-device activity (mouse stuff, keyboard etc)

Comment: What does "current window opened" mean?

Comment: When I use the phase "current window" ,I mean any window opened by the Laptop user.The mouse scroll is controlled via webcam using a specific eye gesture. I not sure how to obtain the name of the window opened to pass to parameter hwnd??

Comment: Any help regarding this topic will be much appreciated. I have also tried mouse_event flag mouse MOUSEVENTF_WHEEL and setscrollinfo none have been successful due to unknown parameter of hwnd and if the steps Im following is correct.

Comment: Perhaps GetForegroundWindow will work for you?

Comment: Thank you so much, I will first test it out and update you on my results.

Comment: I used the following                                               HWND WINAPI wind= GetForegroundWindow();                                SetScrollPos(wind,SB_VERT, -100,true);
UpdateWindow(wind);                                                      The scroll bar doesnt move.When I step through the code, line one produces -wind 0xcccccccccccccccc {unused=??? } HWND__ *
   unused CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated

Comment: @Kribz, have you managed to finish your gaze tracker?

Comment: Yes I did. It was two years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A million years ago, I made a program that would play WinMine (Windows' MineSweeper) for me.

This involved

- (a) Get the HWND of the window with the title "Minesweeper"
- (b) Calling setWindowForeground on it
- (c) Opening the memory of the process and reading some data that
  corresponded to the current game state.
- (d) Examining this memory to determine the number and position of the
  mines
- (e) Moving the mouse to the center of each 'safe' tile before sending
  a left-button down, then a left-button up message

The game could be successfully completeed 100% of the time in under 1 second - the time-remaining component of the high-score was always the same as the total time available for solving the problem. For kicks, I also added code that would set the playing field to be a 1bit image - I.e each cell was safe or not.

Anyhow, the following code works for me: It's just scrolled this post-entry box by 4 lines.

If it's run in debug mode, or with a visible console window - the events are swallowed by it, since it's the foreground window. I've run this code without a window. Editing the code, followed by hitting build, before switching back to this window while the code is building resulted in the scrolling of this input box.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>

const int minWheelMovement = 120;

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance,
                    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    LPSTR lpszArgument,
                    int nCmdShow)
{

    HWND foregroundWindow;
    foregroundWindow = GetForegroundWindow();
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL, 0,0,4*minWheelMovement, 0);
}
```

Comment: @AlexandreMarcondes - Nah, I don't have a github account and aren't inclined to set one up at the moment. I'll chuck it onto pastebin, available for the next 24 hours. Just a minute or two. Do note however - the program no longer functions correctly, as it was written for the version of MineSweeper that came with WindowsXP.

Comment: You're welcome - but remember, it expires 24 hours from now and will no longer be available after then. (assuming that wasn't what you'd intended to keep in mind, of course)